# AngularJS - Any way whatsoever to make execution wait until a promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to wait until a promise is resolved and then proceed with execution?

I know it's not something you usually want to do but this is for interaction with another component which is out of my reach.

Basically the component requires a validation function be defined that returns either true or false but all my validations are promises (and thus, asynchronous). Is there any way to make it work between them or do I have to switch to synchronous calls.

code is as following: (simplified, of course)

```
$scope.comp = new oldComponent(
{
    //blah blah various settings,
    validateFunction: function (someObject) { //this function must return true/false
        return someObject.valid(); //doesn't work as object.valid() returns a promise;       
    }   
}
```

Is there a way to make it work without changing all my validation functions?

Comment: try - var promise = someObject.valid(); promise.then(return /*whatever the result of valid is*/);

Comment: Alternatively, $q.all is capable of combining all promises if you have more than one and waiting until they're all done. Is that of any use?

Comment: @Jorg I'm affraid not. The oldComponent calls the validateFunction and evaluates its return value which in this case would be a promise (not true/false). I can't change it to wait for a promise;

Comment: but can the assignment of `new oldcomponent...` wait until the promise is done?

Comment: @Madhu you mean something like `return someObject.valid().then(function (data) { return data; //this is the result of valid() });` ? I'm pretty sure that will also evaluate to a promise

Comment: @Jorg no, the validateFunction is run at random times way after $scope.comp has been created.

Comment: i don't suppose you want $timeouts or while(function_is_executing) loops :P

Comment: well $timeout also return a promise so that's not much help and I have no idea about the while, but it might be a last resort. I really don't want to make my ajax calls synchronous

Comment: the promise could set a flag like `$scope.done = true` while the rest of your app just sits there and checks for `$scope.done` every 100ms or something. a setInterval would sort that out. It's pretty ugly though, so don't consider this a proper answer...

Comment: Yeah I'll try something like that if there's no other option. I really wish I didn't have to...

Comment: I don't think there is a (non-ugly and non-kittens-die-when-you-use-it) way. Why not share more context on what you can and can't change (and what exactly that `oldComponent` does - we might come up with a better solution...

Comment: @ExpertSystem It's not like there's much to say. oldComponent is an inhouse-built form object and validateFunction is called before the data is submitted. The return value of ValidateFunction is simply checked for true/false values. I have no clearance to change oldComponent in any way or I'd set it up to accept promises myself.

Comment: I also checked the code of oldComponent and even changing it to accept promises would be a LOT of work due to how the component interacts with other stuff.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that if you have to use async stuff in a sync workflow. Your component has to either support some type of async operation (promises, callbacks etc) or it can't be used with async functions :(